# How do i know which DMS rule called a Sitecore component?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

For a project I'm using Sitecore in combination with Sitecore Digital Marketing System(DMS). I want to know if a component was called by a DMS rule; and if a component was called by a DMS rule I want to know by which one. So I can send the results of my DMS rules to Google Analytics. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `Sitecore.Analytics.config` in the `app_config/include` folder.

In there you'll find a reference to `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Personalization` which is a processor in the `insertRenderings` pipeline.

If you decompile that class (it's in Sitecore.Analytics.dll) you will see that it is responsible for taking action when personalization conditions are met.

I think you could probably extend this class to add the functionality you require. Then you can replace the original class reference in the config file with your new one.